# Eclipse code formatter: how to remove its effects?

Tags: java, eclipse

for a mistake i've made eclipse v. 3.4.2 formatting my sourcecode on a single class file.
That's really confusing, how can i restore my own original text format?

Answer (score 8):

The simplest approach is probably to use Eclipse's Local History. On the context menu for the file, select "Restore from local history." If it's not *in* the local history, you may need to  go back to the previous version in source control... (I assume you're using source control. If you're not, I strongly urge you to do so, right away.)

Of course, another option if you've still got the file open is just to press Ctrl-Z to undo actions - keep doing that until the formatting goes away :)

Comment: Your answer is useful, but unluckily i've turned off Eclipse before sleeping :( The "Restore from local history" is empty, and im not using any source control (thanks for the advice, by the way). Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: @mark: I doubt it - I suspect there's nothing you can do other than either tweaking Eclipse's source formatter to look more like yours and then telling it to reformat, or doing it by hand. I *would* recommend that you find some settings you're comfortable with and autoformat the code though - it's nice to be *able* to do that whenever you want.

Comment: I hope someone give me a solution for this particular case, or i really will have fun formatting over 2k lines :P Thanks Jon

Comment: @mark: You've lost the data, it's as simple as that. That's what happens when you make changes without any sort of backup :) You haven't told us what the formatting was like before, which makes it very hard to help you. Why is your class 2000 lines long in the first place?

Comment: Before the formatting-mess the class was about 1k; its the biggest class of the project. Here's an example of the original formatting http://pastebin.com/F0jW7bqA

Comment: @mark: That doesn't really help us much - although the "brace at the end" style is more conventional in Java. Where is Eclipse adding *more* lines though?

Comment: the variables declarations was not affected at a first look. Here is an example of "bad" formatting http://pastebin.com/uFRnXE4Y

Comment: @JonSkeet I received a preformatted code, since it is formated it is very difficult for me to read it. How to undo its formatting

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya: Normally formatted code is *easier* to read. If the formatting style is just not to your taste, edit the Eclipse preferences to your taste and then just reformat everything.