# Eclipse. how to return code state as before formatting

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, formatting

I use `Eclipse` for development. Without thinking, I have formatted all project. Now I click commit in svn and see that I changed every file.   It is very annoying.

Is there way to return code as before formatting?

I could be  make `revert` from svn But at this case I loose change - I will not want make it.

Comment: Eclipse has a _local history_ for each file. Right-click your project and select _Restore from local history_. Additionally, you and your team mates should stick to one formatting rule.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse code formatter: how to remove its effects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711786/eclipse-code-formatter-how-to-remove-its-effects)

Comment: *Without thinking, I have formatted all project* -- You shouldn't blame yourself, but the team (or leader) that didn't choose to have a consistent style in the project in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, you should use a consistent coding style in one project.

**If your project previously had a consistent style** (that was not yours) and you accidentally formatted it with your coding style, then you can:

1. create a project-specific formatter that is consistent with the previous coding style
2. apply this formatting to the whole project
3. commit again

**If your project didn't have such consistency**, then it's time to choose one style and apply it. However, such a commit should be separated from a commit containing actual changes in the code. Therefore you can:

1. Use Eclipse's local history to revert the formatting (as @Seelenvirtuose suggested)
2. Commit your actual code changes
3. Choose one coding style for the project
4. Create a project-specific formatter for the chosen style
5. Reformat the project with this new formatter
6. Do another commit with only style changes this time

Comment: As I understood in our team every developer change format only for affected part of code. Thus all code has differents formats

Comment: @gstackoverflow I know that feel. I'm in the exact same situation in my current team. **This is wrong**. You should try and convince your project leader that a style must be chosen and stay consistent in a project. Eclipse allows project-specific formatters especially for this purpose, let's use it.

Comment: I accepted with this opinion, but we all use different IDE s

Comment: Using a different IDE does not prevent your team members from sticking to a chosen style, does it? Eclipse make it simple to keep your own style for other projects, while sticking to the chosen style for a specific project. I guess other IDEs provide similar functionality. If not, then your team members should adapt their own style, or change IDE because it doesn't suit their needs anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, try "Undo". That works more often than you'd think.

If Undo doesn't work (anymore), then you can use the "Local History" to revert to a previous state of the file.

I suggest to first revert all the files which you didn't change.

Alternatively, you can configure the formatter to produce code which looks like what you currently have in Subversion. That way, you can format the code safely. Or at least reduce the number of differences that you currently see. That will help to clean up the mess.

Lastly, you should consider moving the a modern DVCS.

Comment: I see "Local History" only for file - non for project

Comment: Yes, you have to do this for each file. So the first step is to revert all the files that you didn't change. That should leave you with a short list where you can then use local history to revert the formatting for the rest.